# Как сделать выбор пути к файлам с помощью всплывающего окна tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется функция

```
def extract_text():
    try:
        work_dir = Path(r"D: ")
        sep = ";"
        def join_csv_files(files, **read_csv_kwargs):
            res = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **read_csv_kwargs)
                             for f in files],
                            axis=1)
            return res

        res = join_csv_files(work_dir.glob("*.csv"), sep=sep, usecols=[0, 1], index_col=0)

        res.to_csv(r"D:\res.csv", sep=sep)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы не прописывать путь в переменной  work_dir, а сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать каталог с помощью всплывающего окна. Пытался сделать с помощью askopenfilename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно вы делали

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd 

def callback():
    name= fd.askopenfilename() 
    print(name)

errmsg = 'Error!'
tk.Button(text='Click to Open File', 
       command=callback).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.mainloop()
```